# Fail install minikube

Tags: virtualbox, multipass, minikube

Getting the following error message,   using Windows+VirtualBox

```
C:\Users\x>multipass launch minikube --name minikube -vvvv
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.164] [trace] [k8s1] Got VMState: running
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.166] [debug] [blueprint provider] Loading Blueprint "minikube", version v1
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.197] [debug] [minikube] Running: VBoxManage, controlvm, minikube, poweroff
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.232] [debug] [minikube] VBoxManage failed - errorString: Unknown error, exitStatus: 0, exitCode: 1
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.233] [warning] [minikube] Could not power off VM: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'minikube'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 366 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp

[2023-10-25T11:08:20.233] [debug] [minikube] Running: VBoxManage, unregistervm, minikube, --delete
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.272] [debug] [minikube] VBoxManage failed - errorString: Unknown error, exitStatus: 0, exitCode: 1
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.272] [error] [minikube] Could not unregister VM: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'minikube'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(VMName).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 231 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp

[2023-10-25T11:08:20.272] [warning] [minikube] Could not find the cloud-init ISO path for removal.
launch failed: Unable to find an image matching "default" in remote "".
[2023-10-25T11:08:20.276] [warning] [winterm] Could not find Windows Terminal's settings; location: ""; reason: File not found.
```